# Rails JSON : Empty/Blank data will not save in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, json, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this in my controller

```
@geo.message_notification = {
  trigger_event: params[:ng_geo][:trigger_event],
  ptc: {
    id: params[:ng_geo][:ptc]
  },
  message: params[:ng_geo][:message],
  mode: params[:ng_geo][:mode],
  remind_interval: params[:ng_geo][:remind_interval],
  document: {
    id: params[:ng_geo][:document]
  }
}.to_json
```

will produce JSON:

```
{
  "trigger_event":"IOR",
  "ptc":
  {
    "id":"184"
  },
  "message":"could you please be faster?",
  "mode":"",
  "remind_interval":"",
  "document":
  {
    "id":"234"
  }
}
```

As you can see in the JSON, empty data (mode & remind_interval) still save in db. how to avoid this so will produce just only attr with data:

```
{
  "trigger_event":"IOR",
  "ptc":
  {
    "id":"184"
  },
  "message":"could you please be faster?",
  "document":
  {
    "id":"234"
  }
}
```

Comment: you can do like this  **hash.delete_if { |key, value| value.blank? }** to remove empty value.Here **hash** is your JSON

Answer (score 2):

Well, it seems to me there are some fundamental issues here.

First of all, a controller is not a good place to do this kind of stuff.

Second, you should pass this logic to database wrapper, like active record or mongoid.

Or you could do it quick and dirty:

```
@geo.message_notification = {
...
}.select{|_,v| !v.blank?}.to_json
```

Comment: it works but somehow, document and its id still in the output

`{"trigger_event":"IOR","ptc":{"id":"409"},"message":"could you please be faster?","document":{"id":""}}`

Comment: it means the problem is in your database settings, probably you have all your fields mandatory.

Comment: nope, there is no validation yet.. btw document is an json object inside json. that's why it doesn't not skip this document

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution please:

```
ng_geo_params = params[:ng_geo].slice(:trigger_event, :ptc, :message, :mode, :remind_interval, :document).delete_if { |k, v| v.blank? }
# OR if you can
ng_geo_params = params.require(:ng_geo).permit(:trigger_event, :ptc, :message, :mode, :remind_interval, :document).delete_if { |k, v| v.blank? }

message_notification_hash = {}

ng_geo_params.each do |k, v|
  if k == :ptc || k == :document
    message_notification_hash[k] = { id: v }
  else
    message_notification_hash[k] = v
  end
end

@geo.message_notification = message_notification_hash.to_json
```